# When is config file loaded into memory?

Tags: .net, configuration

Can someone confirm at which point in the life of an `exe` its `config` file is loaded into memory?

Is it when the `exe` itself first loads, or when a `ConfigurationManager` method (e.g. `ConfigurationManager.GetSection(...)`) is first called?

In other words, can I safely edit and save the app's config file before it first calls `ConfigurationManager.GetSection(...)` (or whatever)?

Comment: Are you programmatically changing the application configuration file?

Comment: The config file is *first* read before any of your code ever executes - consider that it can contain e.g. supported runtime information, binding redirects, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The config file is not cached. That is, changes to it made while your application is running will be reflected through calls to ConfigurationManager.

Comment: To be clear, are you saying that the disk file is re-read whenever a ConfigurationManager method is called?

Comment: I don't know if it is literally read each time but certainly it is monitored for changes.